# how to transit to a view controller

Tags: ios

I made a view controller A in storyboard and linked with other view controller. Now I have another view controller B and I want to write a method that can transit from B to A. How can I do this? 
There is a segue to controller A in storyboard.
And controller B is loaded from another view I created programmatically so I can't set a segue in storyboard.

Comment: transit? what do you mean? go from B to A, then can be back to A to B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using storyboard. This is more accurate, try this:

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YOUR VIEW CONTROLLER"];
vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

But be sure to name your view's `identifier` otherwise it will crash and wont work.

Then when you want to dimiss the view:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```